# Passing UserDetails to spring controller

Tags: spring, security, model-view-controller, controller

I'm looking at a simple Spring boot project using spring-webmvc version 4.07 and Spring Security v 3.2. The basic security config is overriden with the following config class to provide secured URLs and a custom UserDetails implementation:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('READER')")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(
              AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .userDetailsService(new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
          UserDetails userDetails = readerRepository.findOne(username);
          if (userDetails != null) {
            return userDetails;
          }
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found.");
        }
      });
  }

}
```

The above readerRepository.findOne(username) is based on the interface

```
public interface ReaderRepository extends JpaRepository<Reader, String> {

    List<Book> findByReader(String reader);

}
```

so it is looking for a Reader in the database with the username provided on the login page. The Reader class is

```
@Entity
public class Reader implements UserDetails {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private String username;

  private String fullname;
  private String password;

  ...Setters/Getters, getAuthorities(), isAccountNonExpired(), isAccountNonLocked(), isCredentialsNonExpired(), isEnabled()

}
```

There is one controller,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@ConfigurationProperties("amazon") 
public class ReadingListController {

    private ReadingListRepository readingListRepository;
  private AmazonProperties amazonConfig;

    @Autowired
    public ReadingListController(ReadingListRepository readingListRepository,
        AmazonProperties amazonConfig) {
        this.readingListRepository = readingListRepository;
    this.amazonConfig = amazonConfig;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String readersBooks(Reader reader, Model model) {
        List<Book> readingList = readingListRepository.findByReader(reader);
        if (readingList != null) {
            model.addAttribute("books", readingList);
            model.addAttribute("reader", reader);
            model.addAttribute("amazonID", amazonConfig.getAssociateId());
        }
        return "readingList";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addToReadingList(Reader reader, Book book) {
        book.setReader(reader);
        readingListRepository.save(book);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

I run the application with the command "gradle bootrun". When I go to localhost:8080/ I am presented with a login page. When I log in, the readerBooks(...) method of the controller is called. This method has a Reader object as a parameter, which contains the logged in reader whose username was entered on the login page. The Reader class (which implements UserDetails) is obviously being passed in by Spring. However, I have never seen it done this way. I have seen it done by passing in a Principal annotated with @AuthenticationPrincipal, or by accessing the SecurityContext from within the controller method, but I can't find anything documenting why the Reader in this case is being passed in. Is it simply because Reader implements UserDetails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer. This is something I have not seen in Spring before. I overlooked one class that is the key to what is going on. A custom implementation of HandlerMethodArgumentResolver was created so that Spring could recognize the Reader class and inject it as is done with the Model parameter:

```
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer;

@Component
public class ReaderHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

  @Override
  public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    return Reader.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
  }

  @Override
  public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
      ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
      WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

    Authentication auth = (Authentication) webRequest.getUserPrincipal();
    return auth != null && auth.getPrincipal() instanceof Reader ? auth.getPrincipal() : null;

  }

}
```

This class has @Component so it will be declared as a bean in the WebConfig.java class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
  }

  @Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(
      List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(new ReaderHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
  }

}
```

With this code in place, Spring will now recognize Reader as a valid parameter to a controller method and inject a Reader class populated with the authenticated principal, if one exists. Otherwise, it will populate Reader with a null. I saw the code in WebConfig.java, but ignored it as I did not recognize what it was for. What I'm still not quite sure about is why the supportsParameter method of the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver class is not something simple like

```
@Override
 public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    return parameter.getParameterType().equals(Reader.class);
 }
```